# Visual Studio looking for Android SDK in the wrong place

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

When I installed Xamarin I selected folder for Android SDK on disk D:\ . Visual Studio wrote an error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1933,3): error MSB6004: Указанное расположение исполняемого файла задачи "D:\XamarinAndroidSdk\\bin\javac.exe" является недопустимым.
```

I copied Android SDK to folder on C:\ . In settings I select a  new folder. When I run project I take error. In settings selected folder on D:\ .

I reinstalled Xamarin. In time of  installing I selected folder on C:\ . I have this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(531,2): error : Could not find android.jar for API Level 23. This means the Android SDK platform for API Level 23 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (D:\XamarinAndroidSdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar missing.)
```

In settings selected folder on C:\ .

How to  fix it?

Upd: I reinstalled Xamarin. Now all is OK:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like API level 23 tools are not installed on your machine.
Open the Android SDK and download the API Level 23 platform tools